# How to disable IIS application pool recycling with AppCmd

Tags: iis, appcmd

I'm working on a tool to configure the recycling feature for a service hosted in IIS Server. In my scenario, the administrator can set the daily "Recycle time" for IIS Application pool. I have tried to use the "Appcmd" tool to set the daily recycle time.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /+recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='00:09:00']
```

However, these are my problems:

1. Every time I use the above command, it actually adds a new "recycle time" to the daily recycle schedule.
2. I can not find a command to remove all the scheduled "Recycle time".

Note: I know there is a solution to programmatically do this. However, I would like to use a simple command line call if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This command should remove all the scheduled recycle time:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool /-recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
```

Before running this command:

[image]

After running this command:

[image]

Comment: I found that this command will remove the <clear> element in the configuration file which I have asked in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903687/iis-recycling-configuration-clear-tag-meaning/48906059?noredirect=1#comment84861644_48906059  Currently, I'm using PowerShell script. I wonder if there is another command that can keep <clear> element?