# IIS recycling configuration "clear" tag meaning

Tags: iis

I'm working on a tool to configure the recycling feature for an application pool in IIS Server. From my understanding, this configuration is stored in the configuration file "applicationHost.config", which is as below

```
    <applicationPools>
        <add name="TestPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
            <recycling>
                <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                    <schedule>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="20:00:00" />
                    </schedule>
                </periodicRestart>
            </recycling>
        </add>
    </applicationPools>
```

My goals are to clear and add new value to the recycle schedule using Command line tool. So far I have been able to completely remove the schedule. However, when I try to add new recycle time value, I can not add the "clear" tag. What is this tag meaning? Can the application pool operate normally without this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition from [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903345(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The **<clear>** element removes all sections and section groups from your application that were defined earlier in the current configuration file or at a higher level in the configuration file hierarchy.

In your case, it's ok to remove the element, but I will suggest you to keep it there for avoiding any exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like it would be OK if I don't have the same configuration at the "higher level".  I would add this element if I can, however, I couldn't figure out how to do this with the command line. (I'm using "AppCmd.exe"). If you have used this tool, please check if this is possible.

Comment: @TranToan try to use the following syntax:
**appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:string /+recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='timeSpan']**

The variable _string_ is the name of the application pool that you want to configuration. The variable _timeSpan_ is in the format d.hh:mm:ss, where d is the optional number of days(The value that you specify must be based on a 24-hour clock). For further information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754494(v=ws.10))

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your solution. However, it does not add the <clear> element, which is my concern in this case.

Comment: @TranToan In this case, the **applicationPools** element can be declared in ApplicationHost.config only. Any attempts to declare **applicationPools** in a configuration file at a different level in the hierarchy results in an error message. Hope the above information clarifies your concerns.