# IIS: Clear parent-level configuration settings using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

As part of the deployment of our IIS application, we clear the **periodicRestart** schedule using the powershell command `Clear-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$name -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule`

On most servers this works as expected, however on one server (which I cannot directly access) we find the app is still restarted at the same time each day. When our support team clears the schedule via the UI it works ok.

Looking at applicationHost.config on a different server, when it is set using our deployment script it looks like:

```
    <recycling>
        <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
        </periodicRestart>
    </recycling>
```

However when set through the UI it looks like:

```
    <recycling>
        <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
            <schedule>
                <clear />
            </schedule>
        </periodicRestart>
    </recycling>
```

From [IIS recycling configuration "clear" tag meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903687/iis-recycling-configuration-clear-tag-meaning) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart/schedule/#child-elements I can see that this **clear** element *"Specifies that the parent-level configuration settings should be removed from the configuration at this level."*

From this I assume that this particular server has a parent-level periodic restart configured somewhere which is taking effect.

Q1: Is it possible to set this **clear** element using powershell?

Q2: Where would this parent-level config be specified? I can't access the server directly but I can ask the support team to take a look at things, but I need to know where to point them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Is it possible to set this clear element using powershell?

This question can be answered in the affirmative, I can set this `clear` element using powershell. According to your description, I did some tests:

When I use the command line code you provided, I get the same result as you, ie without the `clear` element.

```
Clear-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
```

[image]

But when I use the modified command line code below, I get the same result as setting it with the UI.

```
remove-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicrestart.schedule.collection
```

[image]

> Q2: Where would this parent-level config be specified? I can't access
> the server directly but I can ask the support team to take a look at
> things, but I need to know where to point them!

You configure the `<schedule>` element at the server level in the **ApplicationHost.config** file. The parent-level config you are talking about is specified in this server-level file.